# Maps V2 key issue

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

My com.me.ProjectA is a working app that uses Google Maps V2.  I have both Release and Dubug api keys for this app that I got at the Google API console.  The app works perfectly.

I copied projectA renaming it to com.me.ProjectB.  I tested ProjectB on my device and everything ran fine except, as expected, the map would not show because I still had the api keys for the old namespace of ProjectA in the manifest file.

So, I went to the Google API console and got a new debug api key for com.me.ProjectB using my SHA1 debug fingerprint (That I can get in Eclipse by hitting Windows->Prefs->Android-> build) and my com.me.ProjectB namespace and put this into my manifest file.

So, I think I am doing everything right but when I run it on the device I get no map and I get the messages in logcat saying...

```
12-14 16:32:34.389: E/Google Maps Android API(30070): Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.

12-14 16:32:34.399: E/Google Maps Android API(30070): Ensure that the following correspond to what is in the API Console: Package Name: com.me.ProjectB, API Key: AIzaSyAk1dcariCofa7b4pboMGVtReWaDwT_yL4, Certificate Fingerprint: 5A608D32E8A0901CCCD2C519010AD73BE5F609A2 (these are not the real values)
```

And, of course, the namespace, SHA1 fingerprint, and the API key all match.

Did I forget to do something?
Thanks,
Gary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to `completely` remove the application and then install it all over again. As you said you tried to run the project with the key from `Project A`. This key might be got cached and even if you install the application with the new key, the old one will be used.

So before you install your application with the new key, try to remove the application completely from the phone.

You can as well go over this blog post I wrote and make sure you do all the steps right in producing the key:

[Google Maps API V2 Key](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=403)

Comment: Emil, you are a Wiz!  That was apparently the problem.  Thx. Gary